# "Default activity not found"

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I keep getting the "Default activity is not found" error whenever I want to try and run my app. I have tried 'clean project', 'invalidate caches/restart' and restarted my computer.
**UPDATE:** I tried running different projects, but they all give the same error too. This makes me think there must be something wrong with settings.

It works perfectly for my friend, but I get the error that the "Default activity is not found". If I try to launch a specific activity it also says the activity is not found. This is the code in the androidmanifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="ek97.fhict.theapp">
    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/loqate_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/loqate_logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".bottomnavigationfinal"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bottomnavigationfinal"/>
        <activity android:name="Settings" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Registration"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_registration" />
        <activity android:name=".Navigation" />
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <activity
            android:name=".GoogleMaps"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_google_maps" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Profile" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: make sure your SplashScreen must be inside `ek97.fhict.theapp` this package. Or Provide full path inside your manifest splashscreen declaration.

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel it's inside ek97.fhict.theapp , do you have any other suggestions I could try to make it work?

Comment: Refresh/Clean your code & gradle. It might be help you.

Comment: if  you didn't have any mistake ,then you have to clean the project it will be solved

Comment: Rebuild project, Invalidade cache and restart and the last option is restard the device. Cause I believe some devices keep a cache of the application if you uninstall the app just to install again right after

Comment: check are you trying to run `app`  module or anything else???

Comment: After restarting my computer it worked once and now after restarting it doesn't work anymore

Comment: simply set no default activity.

Comment: Hi Esmee. I think there's something wrong with your Run/Debug configuration. Do a quick Google search for it on how to reset it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by making sure all implementation versions were the same, there were some in a 28.0.0 version and others in a 26.1.0. version. Now the app works fine on the emulator. Thanks for your suggestions though

Answer (score 0):

If it works for your friend and it is the same code it could be that all you need to do is to  refresh the  cache of your IDE:

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it still gives me the same error. I have also tried to clean the project but that also gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::
Your manifest is missing default activity
Add to any activity as you consider a default activity

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```